# How do I add non-existing values in from arrayList2 to arrayList1?

Tags: java, arraylist, set, array-merge, no-duplicates

Let's say I have an arrayList1 of Points. The data structure is like this :

`(1,2)->(2,2)->(3,2)->(4,2)->(5,2)`

I have another arrayList2 of Points :

`(2,2)->(1,2)->(8,5)->(9,3)`

How do I compare the two lists and add non-existing values from arrayList2 to arrayList1?

**current solution**

The only method I can think of now is using a for loop to compare each of the Points in arrayList1 such as, `if(!arrayList1.contains(arrayList2.get(i))){ arrayList1.add(arrayList2.get(i)); } i++;`.

Is there a more efficient way or already prepared method from a class? Because I have arrayList1 until arrayList6 to compare and replace....

Comment: @Ouney Yes, I'm using this class : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. **For one-liner lovers** ([**running demo**](http://ideone.com/4vIgPw)):

   ```java
   List<Point> list3 = new ArrayList<Point>(new HashSet<Point>(list1){{ addAll(list2); }});
   ```
2. **Safe version *** ([**running demo**](http://ideone.com/5RKrr8)):

   ```java
   Set<String> tmpSet = new HashSet<String>(arrayList1);
   tmpSet.addAll(arrayList2);
   List<String> mergedList = new ArrayList<String>(tmpSet);
   ```

   * As correctly pointed out by Bruce Wayne, [Double Brace initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1958961/1654265) (the one-liner example, also used in both examples to populate the first two lists) should be used with care, due to the potential drawbacks described in the following article:

   > [Don’t be “Clever”: The Double Curly Braces Anti Pattern](http://blog.jooq.org/2014/12/08/dont-be-clever-the-double-curly-braces-anti-pattern/)

**Explanation**: `Set`s can't contain duplicates, so use one as transition vector.

Example 1 code:

```java
List<String> arrayList1 = new ArrayList<String>(){{ add("One"); add("Two");   }};
List<String> arrayList2 = new ArrayList<String>(){{ add("Two"); add("Three"); }};   
List<String> mergedList = new ArrayList<String>(new HashSet<String>(arrayList1){{ addAll(arrayList2); }});
System.out.println(mergedList);
```

> **Output**:    [One, Two, Three]

Example 2 code:

```java
List<String> arrayList1 = new ArrayList<String>(){{ add("One"); add("Two");   }}; 
List<String> arrayList2 = new ArrayList<String>(){{ add("Two"); add("Three"); }}; 
Set<String> tmpSet = new HashSet<String>(arrayList1);
tmpSet.addAll(arrayList2);
List<String> mergedList = new ArrayList<String>(tmpSet);
System.out.println(mergedList);
```

> **Output**:    [One, Two, Three]

Comment: This is cool! Let's say if I have arrayList3, can I do it in one line too? Like `List<String> mergedList = new ArrayList<String>(new HashSet<String>(arrayList1){{ addAll(arrayList2); addAll(arrayList3); }});`

Comment: Sorry, I was excited until  I forgot to try lol. Thanks! This saved lots of my lines in code!

Comment: @Mark, you're excitement is justified but understand that you're creating **too many** anonymous inner classes in return for *syntactic sugar*. Read [this](http://blog.jooq.org/2014/12/08/dont-be-clever-the-double-curly-braces-anti-pattern/) blog post before you decide that double brace initialization is really what you want. Also, readability **almost always trumps** saving lines of code and I'm not sure if using this pattern is the best thing for you.

Comment: Agreed @Mark, with your updated answer, the OP is certainly more equipped to make an informed decision. Thanks for taking the time to incorporate my suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

If **time complexity** is your main priority, add all the points in `List1` to a `HashSet<Point>`.

Then, for each list thereafter, loop through it and see if the set contains each point and if not, add it to `List1`.

```
Set<Point> pointsInList1 = new HashSet<>(list1);
for(Point p : list2)
{
    if(!pointsInList1.contains(p)) {
        list1.add(p);
        pointsInList1.add(p);
    }
}

//Repeat for other lists
```

This solution is linear with respect to the size of the largest list.

Comment: Isn't this the same or a little bit less complex than my current solution? Just that u are using `HashSet` and a `foreach` loop? You're basically going through each lists, compare each node and add it in if it doesn't exist, right?

Comment: @Mark, The time complexity of your solution (from what I can infer from the snippet) is quadratic or *O(m x n)* where *m* and *n* are the size of the two lists. By using a `HashSet`, you are trading time complexity for space and the check to see if a `Point` exists in `list1` is now an O(1) operation. Therefore the overall time complexity is **linear**.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `Set`. It is a collection with no duplicates. So you can add the same value twice, it will be present only one time.

It means you can add many `List` in your `Set`, you will not have duplicates in it.

```
    Set setA = new HashSet(); 

    ArrayList<Point> points1 = new ArrayList<Point>();
    ArrayList<Point> points2 = new ArrayList<Point>();

    Point element1 = new Point(0,0);
    Point element2 = new Point(0,1);
    Point element3 = new Point(0,0);
    Point element4 = new Point(0,2);

    points1.add(element1); 
    points1.add(element2); 
    points1.add(element3);

    points2.add(element1);
    points2.add(element4);

    setA.addAll(points1);
    setA.addAll(points2);

    Iterator<Point> it = setA.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext())
        System.out.println(it.next());
```

Output :

```
java.awt.Point[x=0,y=0]
java.awt.Point[x=0,y=1]
java.awt.Point[x=0,y=2]
```

Comment: I just add it in my comment.

Answer (score 1):

It can have multiple solutions. As you are using `java.awt.Point` class which already has `equals` method overridden(based on the coordinates).
So, you can easily use `contains` method of `List` class.

```
for(Point point : list2){
     if(!list1.contains(point)){
         list1.add(point);
     }
}
```

Make sure to use `for each` loop for a better performance (Do not use index based loop (It makes a difference if you are using `LinkedList`)).

ii) Another alternative is to use `java.util.Set` and use its method `addAll(Set)`. As Set does not all duplicates and hence will merge the elements efficiently.

Comment: How does a for each loop make for a better, significant performance? Basically, the algorithm is the same with my current solution, right? Compare each node in list2 with list1 and if it doesn't exist in list1, add it to list1, right?

Comment: It does not make any difference with arrayList because it is indexed. So, get(i) takes O(1). But in a linkedList get(i) is O(i) operation because it will have to traverse. So, if you use a index based loop, everytime you call get(i) it will start from 0 and scan but in case of for each                                                                                 - it employs an iterator which holds a reference to current element and does not start from 0. Yes you are doing the same thing but this code was not there when i replied. You can use Set otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
    list2.removeAll(list1);
    list1.addAll(list2);
```

Comment: That will modify all other other lists and I'm not sure if OP wants that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override your equal function in your Point Class

and then you could iterate over these two list, and compare their values.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I compare the two lists

That one is easy, just use equals.

> add non-existing values from arrayList2 to arrayList1

- remove all elements of arrayList1 from arrayList2 and add it to the arrayList2. That way only the new elements will be added to arrayList2
- get the difference (arrayList1 - arrayList2) and add these to arrayList2 (for instance with [CollectionUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html))

Your current solution is probably wrong (it will either skip one element or run forever, depending on your loop):

```
if(arrayList1.contains(arrayList2.get(i))) {
  i++; // this shouldn't be there if done in the loop
} else {
  arrayList1.add(arrayList2.get(i)); // here a ++ is needed if not in the loop
}
```

> Is there a more efficient way

A little advice:
**First, make it work (and have a good UnitTest coverage). Then (and only then!) optimize if needed!**